# Using data.table on large dataset - need to add column that represents #weeks since first occurrence of a group item

Tags: r, data.table

Using data.tables, I'm trying to add a new column that holds the number of weeks since an event within a grouping has occurred. (NOTE: the "week in" after, rather than the difference (so, starting with 1, not zero))

Seeing the data, and my expectations might make this easier to see...

I have the following dataset:

```
library(data.table) 
DT1 <-fread("OrderDate,EventDate,OrderID,EventTypeID,LocationID,EncounterID 
1/12/2012 5:40,01/12/2012 05:40,100001,12344,1,5998887
1/12/2012 5:41,01/12/2012 05:49,100001,12345,1,5998887
1/12/2012 5:42,01/12/2012 06:40,100001,12345,1,5998887
1/12/2012 5:45,01/12/2012 05:45,100002,12344,1,5998887
1/12/2012 5:45,01/12/2012 05:49,100002,12345,1,5998887
8/12/2013 5:25,01/12/2012 06:40,100002,12345,1,5998887
8/12/2013 5:46,01/12/2012 05:46,100003,12344,2,5998887
9/12/2013 5:46,01/12/2012 05:49,100003,12345,2,5998887
1/12/2013 7:40,01/12/2013 07:40,123001,12345,2,6008887
1/12/2013 7:40,01/12/2013 07:41,123001,12346,2,6008887
16/12/2013 7:40,01/12/2013 07:50,123001,12345,2,6008887
17/12/2013 7:40,01/12/2013 07:55,123001,12345,2,6008887")


DT$OrderDate <- as.POSIXct(DT$OrderDate, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
DT$EventDate <- as.POSIXct(DT$EventDate, format="%d/%m/%Y %H:%M")
```

What I'm trying to do is to add column that is the weeks since first occurrence of an encounterID.

```
DT2 <- fread("OrderDate,EventDate,OrderID,EventTypeID,LocationID,EncounterID, WeeksSinceFirstEnc
1/12/2012 5:40,01/12/2012 05:40,100001,12344,1,5998887,1
1/12/2012 5:41,01/12/2012 05:49,100001,12345,1,5998887,1
1/12/2012 5:42,01/12/2012 06:40,100001,12345,1,5998887,1
1/12/2012 5:45,01/12/2012 05:45,100002,12344,1,5998887,1
1/12/2012 5:45,01/12/2012 05:49,100002,12345,1,5998887,1
8/12/2013 5:25,01/12/2012 06:40,100002,12345,1,5998887,1
8/12/2013 5:46,01/12/2012 05:46,100003,12344,2,5998887,2
9/12/2013 5:46,01/12/2012 05:49,100003,12345,2,5998887,2
1/12/2013 7:40,01/12/2013 07:40,123001,12345,2,6008887,1
1/12/2013 7:40,01/12/2013 07:41,123001,12346,2,6008887,1
16/12/2013 7:40,01/12/2013 07:50,123001,12345,2,6008887,3
17/12/2013 7:40,01/12/2013 07:55,123001,12345,2,6008887,3")
```

I'm doing this on a rather large dataset, so efficiency matters. And, I'd like to do this using data.table functions as much as possible.

Can anyone suggest how I can efficiently do this?

Comment: Your desired output (DT2) is unrelated to your input (DT1). I see "17/12" on the last row of the output, while it's "1/12" on the input...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
DT[, WeeksSinceFirstEnc := OrderDate - min(EventDate), by = EncounterID]
DT[, WeeksSinceFirstEnc := as.numeric(DT$WeeksSinceFirstEnc)%/%(60 * 60 * 24 * 7) + 1]
```

First I'm calculating the difference between the first EventDate for eache EncounterID and the OrderDate on each row. The result is saved in a new column, but it's in seconds.

The second step is to convert the seconds to weeks, using the integer division operator (`%/%`) and then adding 1.

I used the data from your second code block, I have 54 where you have 2, because the year for the EventDate is 2013, not 2012.

Update: As per Jan's suggestion I have changed my answer to save memory.

Comment: Hi Mucio :) You should avoid `data.table$<-` operator and use `:=` instead. `:=` updates data in-place while `$<-` makes a copy in memory. In case of big dataset it can have impact. This [Reference semantics vignette](https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-reference-semantics.html) describes it well.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have much practice with date formats, but this seems to work:

```
DT1[,OrderDate:=as.Date(OrderDate,"%d/%m/%Y")]
setkey(DT1,EncounterID,OrderDate)
DT1[,w:=as.numeric(1L+floor((OrderDate-OrderDate[1])/7)),by=EncounterID]
```

The `setkey` call sorts the data.table so that the first date is `OrderDate[1]`. If this always equals the `EventDate`, then you can instead do

```
DT1[,OrderDate:=as.Date(OrderDate,"%d/%m/%Y")]
DT1[,EventDate:=as.Date(EventDate,"%d/%m/%Y")]
DT1[,w:=as.numeric(1L+floor((OrderDate-EventDate)/7)),by=EncounterID]
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up using a variation of this - as I already had my variable in POSIXct format -- and the "/" seemed to throw an error - as '/' is not defined for date objects.